# Future continuous vs. future simple

Tags: future-tense

I wonder if it's correct to say:

> We'll be having a great time.

at the end of [this letter](http://79.175.174.232/content/lessons/11/Intermediate1_2/unit%203/drills/exercise/grammerangwriting/g.swf).

[image]

Shouldn't it be:

> We'll have a great time.

Comment: Am I the only person that can't view that link? Would it be possible to get the text edited into the question. Bare IP addresses leading to .swf files make me nervous.

Comment: @ColleenV: Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are accepted and mean the same thing, the difference is where they are used.  "We'll be having a great time would be used when trying to convince someone to come with me, for example:

> "Come with us (or just me), it will **be** fun!"

On the contrary, "We'll have a great time" would be used once the recipient of the letter was involved, for example:

> We are going to have a great time at the park tomorrow!

Comment: You make a good distinction between the two - would you be a little more explicit about the "you" who is or is not included though. It might be a little tough for someone less fluent in English to understand. 'You' means the recipient of the letter, right? I don't know why there was a DV - it's not mine just to be clear.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes, you is the recipient of the letter.  I, as a native English speaker, see both "We'll be having a great time" and "We'll have a great time" as meaning the same thing.  When I mentioned the implication, I meant it was where it was more commonly used: I would use "be" if I was trying to convince someone to go with me, for example: "Come with us, it will be fun!"  I would not use "be" once that person was involved, for example: "We are going to have a great time at the park tomorrow!"  I will edit my answer to include this.